# Lenovo Y40 unable to boot from the factory recovery USB purchased from Lenovo

Tags: boot, usb, lenovo-laptop

I've purchased a recovery USB from Lenovo for $39.99, but my laptop would not boot from it. Lenovo technical support refuses to provide me with any hint on how I can get it working unless I pay $69.99 more to them (even as my laptop is still under warranty). Despite having been a customer with them for more than 10 years, my experience with them had been particularly frustrating. They wouldn't provide any support for the recovery USB (which I purchased from them).

I would like to think I'm somewhat savvy with computers and have done research on my own on the internet regarding this issue. I suspect the issue with my laptop probably has to do with the UEFI boot mode and the Legacy Boot mode. I've resetted all BIOS settings to the factory default. Currently my laptop's BIOS boot mode is [UEFI]. This should be the mode that was selected when I first received my laptop. The option for USB Boot is [Enabled]. The option for Secure Boot is also [Enabled]. I don't know what else I can do to boot from the recovery USB so I can restore the operating system to initial state. I'd really appreciate if you can drop me a hint. Thank you for your help!

[additional notes]
The laptop came with Windows 8.1 and since I've upgrade my OS to Windows 10. I've been having problems shutting the computer down properly. So I want to revert everything back to the factory setting

Comment: Why did you pay Lenovo for something you can make yourself for free?

Comment: @Ramhound I wanted to restore everything to the factory default..

Comment: Why would you by choice install OEM software?  You don't mention what operating system you are trying to install.

Comment: @Ramhound idk how to make the recovery disk myself for free

Comment: Boot into the `Advanced Start-up` mode.  Choose the option to Reset your system.  Windows 10 will be reinstalled.  If you want Windows 8.1 download the .ISO from Microsoft, create an installation media, and boot to it.

Comment: Microsoft gives free "Media Creation Tool" for Windows 8, 8.1 and Windows 10. This tool can create Installation USB/DVD.

Comment: Laptops boot from USB devices better when they are cold (e.g. in a cold room).

Answer (score 0):

"Media Creation Tool" can be downloaded from Microsoft free.

For Windows 8, Windows 8.1 and Windows 10.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-reset-refresh-media

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/upgrade-product-key-only